# How to change a dropdownlist Selected Item , If the value is folder Path?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm using ASP.net C# MVC, Problem is when I try to change my dropdownlist selected item using JavaScript I get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence!
It's all because, my dropdownlist value is a folder path, so is there any way to fix it out?

Html:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("fileList", ViewBag.FileList as SelectList, "---Select Excel File---", new 
 { @class = "form-control", id = "fileList", required = "required" })
```

JavaScript:

```
var path = '@Session["path"]';
$('#fileList option:selected').val(path).change();
```

C# HomeController:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\umair.farooq\Desktop\FileUploaderProject\FileUploaderProject\UploadedFiles");
 List<SelectListItem> file = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (var s in files)
   {
      file.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = s.Substring(84), Value = s});
   }
ViewBag.FileList = new SelectList(file,"Value","Text");
```

[HttpPost] Method to maintain the state of form or the fields we changed

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        string path = form["filelist"].ToString();
        string sDate = form["dateStart"].ToString();
        string eDate = form["dateEnd"].ToString();
        getFiles();//to fill the dropdownlist
        Session["path"] = path;
        Session["sDate"] = sDate;
        Session["eDate"] = eDate;
        System.Data.DataTable dtbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dtbl = ConvertToDataTable(path, sDate, eDate);
        return View(dtbl);
    }
```

[Inspect View of Selectlist Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRftL.png)

Comment: How does your data in ViewBag.FileList look like?

Comment: I Updated my question and added the Viewbag .FileList code. hope it's understandable Thank you!! :)

Comment: Can you also share one of the actual select `options` actually added to your html code and an example of `var path = '@Session["path"]';`

Comment: yes updated again!

Comment: Hmm you should try and replace backslashes in your js, for example: `var path = ('@Session["path"]').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')`

Comment: *because backslashes have to be escaped

Comment: same error...  You can see an image from the link which I have attached below. Thanks!
https://ibb.co/DYXVLtg

Comment: Can you paste as text

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(path)`?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence